# Array with multi data type

Tags: arrays, object

I'm searching for "Array of object" & "Array with multi data type", and I did not find any useful page. So here's a sample code, can you  to complete it with comments. I appreciate what you need going to do.

```
public class Student 
{
  String[] name = new String[];
  int[] grade = new int[];
}
```

Comment: Which language are we talking about?

Comment: Looks like homework to me ;)

Comment: It is Array of object as you look for: object[] putAnythingInMe = new object[] { 1, "I am a string", new char[] { 'a', 'b' }, 2.5m, DateTime.Now };

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your question is but an array of objects is easy - really, just Google it.

Student class

```
public class Student
{
   public String name;
   public int grade;
}
```

Using the array

```
Student[] students = new Student[x];
int i = students.length;

while(--i != -1)
{
    // Adds students to the array
    students[i] = new Student();
}

students[0].name = "you";
students[0].grade = 1;
students[1].name = "stackoverflow";
students[1].grade = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```